# Upload file to cloud storage using firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I was checking this sample code:

```
// Download file from bucket.
const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
return bucket.file(filePath).download({
  destination: tempFilePath
}).then(() => {
  console.log('Image downloaded locally to', tempFilePath);
  // Generate a thumbnail using ImageMagick.
  return spawn('convert', [tempFilePath, '-thumbnail', '200x200>', tempFilePath]);
}).then(() => {
  console.log('Thumbnail created at', tempFilePath);
  // We add a 'thumb_' prefix to thumbnails file name. That's where we'll upload the thumbnail.
  const thumbFileName = `thumb_${fileName}`;
  const thumbFilePath = path.join(path.dirname(filePath), thumbFileName);
  // Uploading the thumbnail.
  return bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {destination: thumbFilePath});
// Once the thumbnail has been uploaded delete the local file to free up disk space.
}).then(() => fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath));
```

My question is specifically on this line:

```
return bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {destination: thumbFilePath});
```

why are we providing a full file path to the `destination` parameter here? As to my understanding the `destination` parameter indicates the file name it will take after being uploaded to the storage bucket.

So my guess is something like `"thumb_Qsdflsdfa.png"` is enough instead of `"/tmp/../thumb_Qsdflsdfa.png"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/1.2.0/storage/bucket?method=upload), second parameter is optional.

If you don't mind having image name same as your filename in your bucket, then you can leave this blank. e.g. -

`bucket.upload('/local/path/image.png')` - your bucket name will be `image.png`

However, if you would like to name something else that makes sense according to your project, you can pass in a second parameter, like so -

`bucket.upload('/local/path/image.png', { destination: 'thumb_image.png' })` - your bucket name will now be `thumb_image.png`

Hope this makes sense.

Here's a screenshot to make it clear -

[image]

Comment: permission issue? question doesn't say anything about permission

Comment: oh sorry I had two similar question I thought you answered the other one; ok thanks for the explanation and I think your answer makes sense but on the code they are passing the full file path as the destination parameter instead of just file name. Any idea here?

Comment: haha, no worries. So I had a quick test, it looks like `path.join(path.dirname(filePath), thumbFileName);` gives us just the name of the file `thumb_image.png` instead of `myFolder/thumb_image.png` and it does correctly store it within `myFolder/`. So to answer your question, in this example, you need it to define where you want it to be stored but the name it will take will be the file name rather than the whole path name.

Comment: So the whole  ```path.join(path.dirname(filePath), thumbFileName)``` is same as thumbFileName?

Comment: sorry, i might have misinterpreted, the value is `myFolder/thumb_image.png` and it saves it inside `myFolder` with `thumb_image.png` name. I've put a picture for clarity, have a look.